# Throwing errors inside a root Task

Tags: swift

I can't find anything in the docs how the following behavior is defined

```
// task-less context
Task.detached {
    try await myThrowingFunction()
    runWhenSuccessful()
}
```

The method returns on the throwing line and discards the error and `runWhenSuccessful()` will never be called. While it makes sense in some way, I at least expected it to trigger an assertion failure or something for the unhandled error.

What is the correct way to deal with this, since I can't handle errors in any parent task.

Am I expected to wrap everything in the closure in a `do/catch` every time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason Task is designed to silently fail when any errors are thrown inside the closure. Tasks do have a [`result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3851228-result) property that you can read when the task has completed, but according to the documentation it will block the current thread where it's executed.

My preferred solution is to create a convenience initializer for `Task` that takes a failure closure.

This is what my custom initializer looks like, and how it would be used:

```
extension Task where Failure == Never, Success == Void {
    init(priority: TaskPriority? = nil, operation: @escaping () async throws -> Void, `catch`: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
        self.init(priority: priority) {
            do {
                _ = try await operation()
            } catch {
                `catch`(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

Task {
    try await asyncTask()
} catch: { error in
    handle(error)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it just seems apple should have provided a 2nd trailing closure by default for this, instead of this weird behavior.

Comment: Brilliant, and simple! I've added my own answer based on your solution here, the primary difference being I changed it from an initializer to a static `do` method, but the internals are identical. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349401/168179

Comment: Also, a suggestion for your own code, consider adding `@discardableResult` to your initializer to stop compiler warnings when you aren't storing the resulting `Task`. 

Comment: If you wrap do/catch then you can’t take advantage of catch let and catch as syntax as a well as multiple catches.

Answer (score 0):

While it has not been officially proposed (*reader: please do that if you're so inclined!*), there has been [talk on the Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/task-initializer-with-throwing-closure-swallows-error/56066/) that only allowing for `Task<Void, Never>` to be "`@discardableResult`" would be a good enough solution to the problem.

As it is now, [`Task.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5k89c) and [`Task.detached`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/detached(priority:operation:)-8a4p6) are always `discardable`. If they were not, the thinking goes, the "`Result … is unused`" message would cause the programmer to be aware that further action is warranted…

…e.g. by explicitly disregarding a result when the task's `Success` is not `Void`…

```swift
_ = Task { "" }
```

…or by being nudged to store the task, and deal with the error later.

```swift
let task = // Task<Void, Error>
  Task.detached {
    try await myThrowingFunction()
    runWhenSuccessful()
  }

await task.value // Property access can throw but is not marked with 'try'
```

I support this proposed change. But it would still be possible, as it is now, to disregard a task that completed with an error, using an underscore, and I don't think that underscore represents intent very well:

```swift
_ = Task.detached {
  try await myThrowingFunction()
  runWhenSuccessful()
}
```

The only way to enforce handling of the error is to get the idea that the `operation` closure does not throw, into the type system, using an explicit `Never`.

> `invalid conversion from throwing function of type '@Sendable () async throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '@Sendable () async -> ()'`

```swift
Task<_, Never>.detached {
  try await myThrowingFunction()
  runWhenSuccessful()
}
```

`do/catch`:

```swift
Task<_, Never>.detached {
  do {
    try await myThrowingFunction()
    runWhenSuccessful()
  } catch { }
}
```

Explicit `Error` perhaps carries a better idea of intention than `_ = Task`:

```swift
Task<_, Error>.detached {
  try await myThrowingFunction()
  runWhenSuccessful()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Task.do/catch

Below is an extension method on `Task` that allows simple and familiar `do/catch` syntax for handling errors in async operations.

The design is based on Emilio Pelaez's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70314338/168179) here on the same page where he used a custom initializer with a trailing `catch` handler.  I've instead implemented it as a static method called `do`, also with a trailing `catch` handler, to be more similar with the familiar `do/catch` syntax Swift developers are used to.  The intent is to add clarity at the call site, a core tenet of Swift's [API design guidelines](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

That said, the majority of the credit goes to his answer for the overall concept so if you like this, please vote him up as well.

```swift
extension Task
where Success == Void,
      Failure == Never {

    typealias ThrowingOperation = () async throws -> Void
    typealias ErrorHandler = (Error) async -> Void

    /// Creates a throwing task with familiar do-catch-like syntax
    @discardableResult
    static func `do`(
        priority: TaskPriority? = nil,
        throwingOperation: @escaping ThrowingOperation,
        `catch` errorHandler: @escaping ErrorHandler
    ) -> Self {
        
        return Task(priority: priority) {
            do { try await throwingOperation() }
            catch { await errorHandler(error) }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above in place, here's how you use it:

```swift
func tryToSleep() {

    // Start's an async 'do' operation
    Task.do { // You're now in a task so you can 'await' as needed
        print("My task is going to sleep asynchronously...")
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(4))
        print("Grrr! I woke up!")
        throw SleepError.notAMorningPerson
    }
    catch: { error in // All unhandled errors thrown in the task are passed here
        print("The task threw an error: \(error)")
    }
}
```